# What are these numbers on the right side of my Windows Phone Silverlight app?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I've got a Windows Phone Silverlight app, and there are some numbers to the right when I run the emulator:

[image]

What do they mean, and how can I hide them?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

That's the frame rate counter for the emulator / phone that is on by default whenever you debug. To turn it off, go to App.xaml.cs and comment this line out:

```
Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;
```

For more information on what the numbers mean (they can be pretty helpful for tracking app performance), see [Jeff Wilcox's post](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/) on this.

Comment: And all others numbers?