# How can I disable the small letters in the WP7 emulator?

Tags: windows-phone-7, emulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are these numbers on the right side of my Windows Phone Silverlight app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393485/what-are-these-numbers-on-the-right-side-of-my-windows-phone-silverlight-app)

For example:

[image]

Those letters kind of get in the way of me seeing what the design looks like as a whole, can I disable them?

Comment: I agree, can we however merge these questions so that if someone reaches here they can find the answer? Maybe someone words their query the same way I did.

Comment: Have flagged as duplicate so this one will be deleted and people won't get here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look in your App.xaml.cs file. You can enable/disable these features by uncommenting or commenting a few lines in there.