# Windows Phone 8 Simulator shows numbers on right side

Tags: simulator, windows-phone-8

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are these numbers on the right side of my Windows Phone Silverlight app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393485/what-are-these-numbers-on-the-right-side-of-my-windows-phone-silverlight-app)

I have created a Windows Phone 8 application using the default template. However, when I run it the simulator displays a lot of numbers on the rights side of the simulator. How can I remove these numbers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The numbers displayed are actually a framerate counter. The default project template enables the framerate counter when a debugger is attached. To hide the framerate counter, go to **App.xaml.cs** and remove (or comment) the following line:

`Application.Current.Host.Settings.EnableFrameRateCounter = true;`

Of course, you can also set the value to `false`.

When you have done this, build and run your application again and the numbers won't be displayed anymore.