# Unidentified UI portion windows phone 8

Tags: user-interface, windows-phone-8

http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/images/thumb/9/9c/One.png/360px-One.png
http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/images/thumb/9/9c/One.png/360px-One.png

The image in this link shows some unidentified UI portion on the top right of the screen. Can someone please describe why it keeps on showing ?
I am unable to identify and correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These framerate counters only shows up in development when the debugger is attached. You'll notice if you run your app when Visual Studio isn't connected and running this UI will disappear.

Here's some more info about it:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/gg588380(v=vs.105).aspx

And how to hide it if your really want to:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5393504/250254

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/07/counters/